# Anonymous PL/SQL Block to call a procedure with collection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to test a package procedure which accepts a PL/SQL table and returns SYS_REFCURSOR.

What I am looking for is Anonymous PL/SQL block which does the following :

- populates PL/SQL table and pass to procedure

The relevant code is below:

```
create or replace type rec_typ as object
        (
                fname varchar2(10),
                lname varchar2(10)
        )
 /
 create or replace type rec_arr as table of rec_typ
 /
 create or replace package get_emp_pkg
 as
     procedure get_emp
      (
           l_rec rec_arr,
           p_out out sys_refcursor
    );
 end;
 /

 create or replace package body get_emp_pkg
 as

    procedure get_emp
    (
            l_rec rec_arr,
            p_out out sys_refcursor
    )
    as
            l_out rec_arr;
    begin

            open p_out for select * from table ( l_out );
    end;

end;
/
```

Comment: what do you want to test? And what did you try?

Comment: @smnbbrv - simply be able to call the procedure with dummy values and print out cursor results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare and populate a table collection, and declare a cursor variable; and then pass those into the procedure call; e.g.:

```
declare
  l_rec rec_arr;
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  l_rec := rec_arr(rec_typ('Joe','Bloggs'), rec_typ('Mary','Berry'));
  get_emp_pkg.get_emp(l_rec, l_cur);
  -- do something with the cursor
  close l_cur;
end;
/
```

If you are just testing it and you're using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you could simplify this to use a client bind variable:

```
variable cur refcursor;

declare
  l_rec rec_arr;
begin
  l_rec := rec_arr(rec_typ('Joe','Bloggs'), rec_typ('Mary','Berry'));
  get_emp_pkg.get_emp(l_rec, :cur);
end;
/

print cur;
```

or even more simply:

```
variable cur refcursor;

begin
  get_emp_pkg.get_emp(rec_arr(rec_typ('Joe','Bloggs'), rec_typ('Mary','Berry')), :cur);
end;
/

print cur;
```

and you could even replace that with an `execute` call, which is just a wrapper for an anonymous block anyway, so functionally almost identical.

Your procedure has a mistake though; you're declaring a local `l_out` variable and then opening the ref cursor based on that, but you don't ever populate it - so the ref cursor result set will always be empty. If you change it to use `l_rec` instead (though I would call that `p_rec`, with the `p_` prefix indicating a parameters and leave the `l_` prefix for local variables):

```
 create or replace package body get_emp_pkg
 as

    procedure get_emp
    (
            l_rec rec_arr,
            p_out out sys_refcursor
    )
    as
    begin
            open p_out for select * from table ( l_rec );
    end get_emp;

end;
/
```

then the bind variable versions above both see:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


FNAME      LNAME     
---------- ----------
Joe        Bloggs    
Mary       Berry
```